# Issue with Greek Characters Printing in Ionic 5 App via Bluetooth Thermal Printer

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, character-encoding, thermal-printer

I'm developing an app using Ionic 5 that features printing receipts through Bluetooth-connected thermal printers. Despite setting the encoding to support Greek characters, the output is incorrect, displaying weird symbols instead of the expected Greek text.

Applied various encodings, specifically cp-1253 and iso-8859-7, with the printer's code page set to 90. These settings work perfectly in another application (an APK that I tested), where Greek characters print correctly.
Ensured that the printer is capable of printing Greek characters by using the test APK.
However, when applying the same settings in my Ionic 5 app, the Greek characters do not print correctly. It seems like the issue is specific to how my app handles the encoding or communicates with the printer.

Comment: Printer control codes and supported code page mappings can often vary depending on vendor and model. Please check the detailed specifications of the device you are using to see if it is different from others.